# Having problems reversing a linked list queue

Tags: java, linked-list

This is part of a homework assignment and I am in no way proficient in Java as I'm still a student and am taking the time out of my day to learn, all feedback is much appreciated!

I'm working on reversing a queue that's been initialized through a linked list, I couldn't figure out a simpler way to do it so I ended up holding each value into an array and then printing the array in reverse.

This is the method I've come up with:

```
@Override
public void reverseDisplay() {
    System.out.println("The values of this linked list in reverse are: ");
    T[] hold;
    hold = (T[]) new Object[numElements];
    int count = 0;
    do {
        rear = front;
        hold[count] = front.getInfo();
        count++;
        front = front.getLink();
    } while (rear.getLink() != null);
    for (int i = hold.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print((i+1) + ": ");
        System.out.println(hold[i]);
    }
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner A1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    LinkedUnbndQueue Q = new LinkedUnbndQueue();
    while (!"-1".equals(input)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the next value of your queue");
            input = A1.nextLine();
            Q.enqueue(input);
        }
    //Q.display();
    //Q.retElements();
    Q.reverseDisplay();
}
```

On run-time everything works perfectly, but when I enter -1 I get thrown an "ArrayIndex out of bounds exception" that takes me to this line:

```
            hold[count] = front.getInfo();
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here? If any extra information is required let me know!

This was the original class I was editing: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall12/CSCI-GA.1133-001/programs/Queues/LinkedUnbndQueue.txt

The answer @luk2302 provides solves the problems I was having!
But now I need to figure out how to reset the linked list after running my display method prior to reversing the list.

This is my display method:

```
@Override
public void display() {
    System.out.println("The values of this linked list are: ");
    int counter = 1;
    do {
        rear = front;
        System.out.print((counter) + ": ");
        counter++;
        System.out.println(front.getInfo());
        front = front.getLink();
    } while (rear.getLink() != null);
}
```

Comment: You may want to link the resources you depend on like http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall12/CSCI-GA.1133-001/programs/Queues/LinkedUnbndQueue.txt

Comment: Good idea! I actually had no idea where to find these resources, our professor just archived all the files in the book and sent them to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should actually dismiss the `-1` value. Your current code appends the -1 to the list and then prints the list. I am guessing the -1 should not actually be appended:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter the next value of your queue");
    input = A1.nextLine();
    if ("-1".equals(input)) {
        break;
    }
    Q.enqueue(input);
}
```

Then lets go to the actual reversal:

I do not know where you currently get the `numElements` from, therefore my function would start with something like:

```
void reverseDisplay() {        
    System.out.println("The values of this linked list in reverse are: ");

    if (isEmpty())
        return;

    int numElements = 1;
    LLNode elem = front;
    while ((elem = elem.getLink()) != null) {
        numElements++;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now we know the length of the actual list. Keeping your remaining code will print

> Enter the next value of your queue
>   0
>   Enter the next value of your queue
>   10
>   Enter the next value of your queue
>   30
>   Enter the next value of your queue
>   50
>   Enter the next value of your queue
>   -1
>   The values of this linked list in reverse are:
>   4: 50
>   3: 30
>   2: 10
>   1: 0

Note that writing to the `front` and or `rear` breaks the remaining logic of the List, you must not change their values, only read from them.

Comment: I'm reading into your comment now, I've initialized numElements in the main class and have it increase by 1 everytime the enqueue method is called and go down by 1 every time the dequeue method is called. I'll post back soon with results!

Comment: @K.Saudi that probably is not the right way to go, you do not want to have global state in some unrelated variable, my approach is better in this regard.

Comment: Alright, I've tested it out and  for some reason, when you've added the isEmpty at the start it's returning true, even though the linked list has elements in it, can't figure out why though. I'm taking a look now

Comment: That explains why if I remove the ifEmpty I'm getting a NullPointerException any idea why the program would think the Front = Null?

Comment: @K.Saudi No. Try debugging it step by step, looking into if the front ever gets non-null and at what point it gets set back!?

Comment: Sorry! I'll do that now, I'm still new to using IDE's and programming in general so please bear with me :) 

I'm having trouble with this :(

Comment: My display method seems to break the code, I've edited the main post to include that method.
I see why running that method prior to the reverseDisplay method would mess things up, I'm heading out now I'll try and work up a fix when I'm back. The reason it worked for you is because I had initially commented out that method from my main class..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @K.Saudi I added a note regarding the breaking of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `A1.nextLine()` before the while loop like this:

```
   System.out.println("Enter the next value of your queue");
    String input = A1.nextLine();
   while (!"-1".equals(input)) {
        Q.enqueue(input);
    }
```

Or add new condition or a counter like this:

```
  while (!"-1".equals(input) && condition) {
        count++;
        Q.enqueue(input);
    }
```

Counter:

```
 int count = 0 ;
 while (!"-1".equals(input) && count < 5) {
        count++;
        Q.enqueue(input);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just give me an infinite loop?

Comment: @K. Saudi But just you can do thing like above

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but I think the point of the linked list queue is to have it unbound (I.E taking an unlimited amount of values concurrent with the amount the user is using) so adding a counter would defeat the purpose. I appreciate the input though!